# how can i add an array of html tags to jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx, react-dom

I am new in react and I have an issue that I didn't find any solution for after search.

When I store the array of html tags in variable I get `minified React error #31`

```
var k = [1,2,3];
var x = k.map(e=><li>{e}</li>);
var e = (
  <div>         
    <ul>
      {1 && {x}}
    <ul>
  </div>
);
var divTag = document.getElementById("k");
ReactDOM.render(e,divTag)
```

But when I write this I get no errors.

```
var k = [1,2,3];
var x = k.map(e=><li>{e}</li>);
var e = (
  <div>         
    <ul>
      {1 && k.map(e=><li>{e}</li>)}
    <ul>
  </div>
);
var divTag = document.getElementById("k");
ReactDOM.render(e,divTag)
```

Comment: Actually, on second look it is your render conditional making the object. `{1 && {x}}` should just be `{1 && x}`. The first creates an object which is invalid as a child `{1 && {x: [...]}`

Comment: Use `{1 && x}` because `{x} is interpreted as the object literal property value shorthand for `{x: x}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the curly braces around the `x` variable `{1 && {x}} -> {1 && x}`

You are defining a new object containing the key `x` instead of just passing the array to react

Answer (score 0):

**The solution**

Replace `{1 && {x}}` with `{1 && x}`

Because you've wrapped `x` into curly braces, you've got the rendering error (you wanted to provide the array).